# Is transfer via database link in Oracle 10g compressed ? Is it possible?

Tags: oracle, bandwidth, database-link, oracle-net-services

I'm transferring data from one base to another via database links (using `INSERT INTO SELECT ...`).

I want to know if data transferred through the link is compressed or can be compressed to avoid too much network use. I have very little bandwidth, and I think that would help if it's not already done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's some [de-duplication](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2010/05/07/sqlnet-compression/) but no serious compression.

There is a UTL_COMPRESS function but it would be tricky to get that to decompress on the destination (maybe a trigger, or instead of view - but it is clunky).

EXPDP can use a database link ([NETWORK_LINK](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm#sthref143)) and, in 11g, [compression](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/DataPumpEnhancements_11gR1.php#compression) but that does require the [Advanced Compression option to be licensed](http://The%20DATA_ONLY%20option%20requires%20that%20the%20Oracle%20Advanced%20Compression%20option%20be%20enabled.).

Lastly there's conventional extract, zip, transfer, unzip, load

In 11gR2 you can use external tables with a [preprocessor to unzip](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/6135/oracle-rdbms-11gr2-new-preprocessor-syntax-for-external-table-use), so you could semi-automate that final option.

Answer (score 2):

As @Gary says, not natively, but it's possible to get compression using an SSH tunnel, assuming you have command-line access anyway. The SSH man page notes that compression can slow things down on a fast network, but that trade-off may be worth it if you're severely bandwidth-constrained; and you may need to experiment with `CompressionLevel` in `ssh_config` to get the best results for your situation.

For example, if your existing link is defined to connect to `remote_server` port `1521`:

```
create database link direct connect to usr identified by pwd
using 'DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=remote_server)(PORT=1521))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=remote_service)))'
```

You can create an SSH tunnel using a free local port, with something like:

```
ssh -C -N -L1522:localhost:1521 remote_server
```

And then you can have a DB link that points to the local side of the tunnel:

```
create database link direct connect to usr identified by pwd
using 'DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1522))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=remote_service)))'
```

So you just change the host and port. If your existing link is using a `tnsnames` entry then you can just modify that instead, to point to `localhost:1522` instead of `remote_server:1521`.

Of course you have to make sure the SSH link is up whenever you use the DB link. If it's down you'll get an `ORA-12541: TNS:no listener` error, since nothing will be listening on your local port 1522.